# date conversion in CodeIgniter / PHP does not gives output

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have date in this type of format: `April 1st 2017` and I want to convert it into this type of format: `2017/04/01` in my `CodeIgniter` code using `php`. I have used below posted piece of code but it is not working. Please solve the issue.

**Code:**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', "April 1st 2017");
echo "Date = ".$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation of [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)? Does `April 1st 2017` looks to you like it follows the `m/d/Y` format?

Answer (score 1):

You can use strtotime() and date() php functions as

```
$newDate = date("m/d/Y", strtotime("April 1st 2017"));
```

Or in CodeIgniter

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j F Y - H:i', 'April 1st 2017');
echo $date->format('m/d/Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: *"Or in CodeIgniter"* -- ??? `strtotime()` and `date()` cannot be used in CodeIgniter?

Comment: @axiac, I have used both PHP functions in CodeIgniter. It worked

Comment: In its current form, the answer suggests that only the code that uses `DateTime` is possible with CodeIgniter (or that CI provides the `DateTime` class, which is not true.)

Comment: Thanks, @axiac, but he also mentioned php. this is " in my CodeIgniter code using php"

Comment: CodeIgniter is not involved in any way in the question or in this answer. It is plain PHP code, it works the same no matter what framework one uses (it doesn't even need or care about the framework).

Comment: Right @axiac but as I have read the question I thought he is also looking in php. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Your format can be used in the constructor of [`DateTime`](https://secure.php.net/datetime). See [accepted formats](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php).

```
$date = new DateTime("April 1st 2017");
echo "Date = ".$date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Outputs:

```
Date = 2017-04-01
```

If you want to use `DateTime::createFromFormat()`, you have to use the proper format

```
"F jS Y"
```

Answer (score 0):

The format you specified for your date is incorrect.

It would convert '04/01/2017' but it does not suit
*April 1st 2017*.

Try instead: `createFromFormat('F dS Y')`

Explanation:

`F` - full textual representation of a month, such as January.

`d` - day

`S` - English ordinal suffix for the day of the month

`Y` - 4-digit representation of year

Answer (score 0):

you can try this also

```
<?php
$date='22 march 2018';
 echo date('m/d/Y', strtotime($date));
?>
```

Comment: this doesn't add anything new to what Gufran had already proposed